# Add delay to JS animated text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, typography

So I have the code below for a auto typing text animation. The text is in front of a image and I want people to see the full picture first and then the text starts to "type". I guess the best way is to add a 2-3 seconds delay before the text starts to animate but I'm not really sure how to do that.

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

```
function cursorAnimation() {
  $('#cursor').animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 'fast', 'swing').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 'fast', 'swing');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('cursorAnimation()', 1000);
});

var text = 'TEXT GOES HERE';

$.each(text.split(''), function(i, letter) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#container').html($('#container').html() + letter);
  }, 110 * i);
});
```

Comment: If you wrote that code then you already know how to use setTimeout()...

Comment: I didn't write the code. It's part of a project I'm on and the back end developer is on vaccation. Instead of waiting for his reply I wanted to get it done on my own. I'm just a simple designer that know my way around some code. :)

Comment: There are already function used to set delay in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some arbitrary delay is NOT the best way. You never know how much time an image will take to load on different kinds of networks, some are very fast, others might be very slow.

Instead you should fire your code on some event e.g. when the image has loaded. You can run your code on window load as an option as shown below:

```
function cursorAnimation() {
  $('#cursor').animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 'fast', 'swing').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 'fast', 'swing');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('cursorAnimation()', 1000);

  $(window).on("load", function(){
    // do here tasks that you want to run after all page assets e.g. images have been loaded
    showText();
  });//window load()
});

function showText() {
  var text = 'TEXT GOES HERE';
  $.each(text.split(''), function(i, letter) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#container').html($('#container').html() + letter);
    }, 110 * i);
  });
}
```

Comment: That's very true. I wasnt very specific regarding the project, it's a showcase of a prototype that will be shown locally so the loading time wont be a problem. But i see this as the best way if the project goes live. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTimeout() function to call your function after some time i.e

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(yourfunction(), 1000); //changes milliseconds as per your need.
})
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

Generaly. It is done that you pack delayed code into callback and that callback you pass into setTimeout method. For preserving functionality while working in objects. I recomentd to call `bind(this)` on packaged callback.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Delayed message");
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

In your case

```
function cursorAnimation() {
  $('#cursor').animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 'fast', 'swing').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 'fast', 'swing');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('cursorAnimation()', 1000);
});

var text = 'TEXT GOES HERE';

setTimeout(function () {
    // delayed code
    $.each(text.split(''), function(i, letter) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#container').html($('#container').html() + letter);
    }, 110 * i);
    });
    // end of delayed code
}.bind(this), 3000);
```